# PHP Arithmetic Operations, How to echo resultant value in short form?

Tags: php, math

I am doing a simple operation, `$c = $a / $b` and getting a result like,

```
12.0123456789
```

I just want the result of `echo $c;` like `12.01` or, `12.012` or, `12.0123` or `12.custom`.

Is it possible? And if it is, my question is how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a documentation reading and paraphrasing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straight forward with [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$a = 120123;
$b = 10000;

echo number_format($a / $b, 2); // Outputs 12.01
echo number_format($a / $b, 3); // Outputs 12.012
echo number_format($a / $b, 4); // Outputs 12.0123
```

Alternatively, you can use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) (or just plain [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)) and get the same output but without `number_format`'s default thousands grouping:

```
$a = 120123;
$b = 10000;

printf("%.2f", $a / $b); // Outputs 12.01
printf("%.3f", $a / $b); // Outputs 12.012
printf("%.4f", $a / $b); // Outputs 12.0123
```

Comment: or sprintf(). number_Format is more for creating human-readable numbers with separators and whatnot.

Comment: I am a beginner & its true that I have asked a simple question here. Don't know why, today my reputation is (-2)! 

@Sean Bright Thanks for your help. I have got my answer.